# How to clean a list in a template

Tags: python, html, css, django

I am currently working on my first website. Which is a rna to a protein translator. What it does is you input a dna chain and it translates it into a protein. However, when i get the protein, it appears like this:

[image]

As you can see, the protein isn't cleaned, which means that instead of appearing as `Isoleucine,glycine` it appears as `['Isoleucine','Glycine']`
Here's the code for that (my guess is there's a problem in the output part):

```
class TranslatorView(View):
    template_name = 'main/translated.html'

    rna_mapper = {
        "a": "u",
        "t": "a",
        "c": "g",
        "g": "c"
    }

    amino_mapper={
        "aat": "Asparagine",
        "aac": "Asparagine",
        "aaa": "Lysine",
        "aag": "Lysine",
        "act": "Threonine",
        "acc": "Threonine",
        "aca": "Threonine",
        "acg": "Threonine",
        "agt": "Serine",
        "agc": "Serine",
        "aga": "Arginine",
        "agg": "Arginine",
        "att": "Isoleucine",
        "atc": "Isoleucine",
        "ata": "Isoleucine",
        "atg": "Methionine",
        "cat": "Histidine",
        "cac": "Histidine",
        "caa": "Glutamine",
        "cag": "Glutamine",
        "cct": "Proline",
        "ccc": "Proline",
        "cca": "Proline",
        "ccg": "Proline",
        "cgt": "Arginine",
        "cgc": "Arginine",
        "cga": "Arginine",
        "cgg": "Arginine",
        "ctt": "Leucine",
        "ctc": "Leucine",
        "cta": "Leucine",
        "ctg": "Leucine",
        "gat": "Aspartic",
        "gac": "Aspartic",
        "gaa": "Glutamic",
        "gag": "Glutamic",
        "gct": "Alanine",
        "gcc": "Alanine",
        "gca": "Alanine",
        "gcg": "Alanine",
        "ggt": "Glycine",
        "ggc": "Glycine", 
        "gga": "Glycine",
        "ggg": "Glycine",
        "gtt": "Valine",
        "gtc": "Valine",
        "gta": "Valine",
        "gtg": "Valine",
        "tat": "Tyrosine",
        "tac": "Tyrosine",
        "taa": "Stop",
        "tag": "Stop",
        "tct": "Serine",
        "tcc": "Serine",
        "tca": "Serine",
        "tcg": "Serine",
        "tgt": "Cysteine",
        "tgc": "Cysteine",
        "tga": "Stop",
        "tgg": "Tryptophan",
        "ttt": "Phenylalanine",
        "ttc": "Phenylalanine",
        "tta": "Leucine",
        "ttg": "Leucine",

    }

    def translate(self, phrase):
        translation = ""
        for letter in phrase:
            if letter.lower() in self.rna_mapper:
                translation += self.rna_mapper[letter.lower()].upper() if letter.isupper() else self.rna_mapper[letter]
        return translation

    def translate_amino(self, codon):
        return self.amino_mapper.get(codon, "")
    
    def build_protein(self, phrase): #Here's where I think the problem is
        protein = []
        i = 0
        while i < len(phrase):
            codon = phrase[i: i + 3]
            amino = self.translate_amino(codon)
            if amino:
                protein.append(amino)
            else:
                print(f"The codon {codon} is not in self.mapper_1")
            i += 3
        return protein

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, 'main/translator.html')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        phrase = request.POST.get('text', 'translation')
        protein = request.POST.get('text','protein')
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'translation': self.translate(phrase), 'protein': self.build_protein(protein)})
```

If you need the template to understand it more, here it is:

`````
{% extends "base.html"%}

{% block content%}

<div >
    
    <h2 class = "display-3">DNA TRANSLATED SUCCESFULLY </h2>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

  
    <h2>
        {{ translation }}
    </h2>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
   
    <h2 class = "display-4">YOUR PROTEIN IS</h2>

    <div class = "protein_image"></div>

    <br>
    <br>

    <h2>
        {{ protein }} 
    </h2>





    <button class= "button_with_image_save" value="Back" onclick="window.history.back()" ></button>
````
`````

Comment: You mean, you want to remove [ ] from the result?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you're looking for the [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) function:

```
class TranslatorView(View):
    ...
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'translation': self.translate(phrase), 'protein': ", ".join(self.build_protein(protein))})
```

Answer (score 1):

in template just use [join tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#join)

```
{{ protein|join:", " }}
```

or if you'll need a html list, you should probably use [for loap](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for)

```html
<ul>
{% for i in protein %}
<li>{{ i }}</li>
{% empty %}
<li>no protein found</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change build_protein like this:

```
    def build_protein(self, phrase): #Here's where I think the problem is
        protein = ''
        i = 0
        while i < len(phrase):
            codon = phrase[i: i + 3]
            amino = self.translate_amino(codon)
            if amino:
                protein = f"{protein},{amino}" 
            else:
                print(f"The codon {codon} is not in self.mapper_1")
            i += 3
        return protein
```

Comment: This is a valid answer, but it's much easier to store the values in a list and then using the `join` function.

Comment: Why it is easier?

Comment: Well, maybe not easier, but I would argue its more "pythonic"